# Proper way to perform the INSERT statement from C# to MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, optimization, sql-insert

I created this function that inserts new records -- I submit query directly to it.
My question- is it optimal? It is it fool proof and guaranteed to function normally? If not; please advise.

```
static String Server = "";
static String Username = "";
static String Name = "";
static String password = "";

static String conString = "SERVER=" + Server + ";DATABASE=" + Name + ";UID=" + Username + ";PASSWORD=" + password + ";connect timeout=500000;Compress=true;";

public bool InsertSQL(String Query)
{
    int tmp = 0;
    try
    {
        using (MySqlConnection mycon = new MySqlConnection(conString))
        {
            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(Query, mycon))
            {
                mycon.Open();
                try
                {
                    tmp = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch
                {
                    if (mycon.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                    {
                        mycon.Close();
                    }
                }
                mycon.Close();
            }
        }
    }
    catch { return tmp > 0 == true ? true : false; }
    return tmp > 0 == true ? true : false;
}
```

This is my SQL insert that I create in other function and pass as text to insert function. I am open to all suggestions!

```
String insertSql = @"INSERT INTO `gps_unit_location`
            (`idgps_unit`,`lat`,`long`,`ip`,`unique_id`,
            `loc_age`,`reason_code`,`speed_kmh`,
            `VehHdg`,`Odometer`,`event_time_gmt_unix`,`switches`, `engine_on_off`, `dt`)
                VALUES
            (
            (Select idgps_unit from gps_unit where serial=" + serial + "),'" + lat + "','" + lon + "','" + IP + "','" + unique_id + @"',
            '" + LocAge_mins + "','" + ReasonCode + "','" + Speed + @"',
            '" + VehHdg + "','" + Odometer + "','" + EventTime_GMTUnix + "','" + Switches + "', '" + engine_on_off + @"', DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR))
            ";
```

Comment: Where are you setting the query object?

Comment: It is set in other function and passed as text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By making this so generic, you are leaving yourself open to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). I am guessing you have to build the query and insert values directly. SQL parameters would be better here, you could potentially pass in a `params` of `SqlParameters`, however that would still rely on generic text being sent and still leaves you open to an injection.

[Here is a SQL Parameter example](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter)

Comment: What would be your suggestion? I added query example. Could you suggest how would you do that?

Comment: @Andrew I posted how to use SQL Parameters

Comment: Based on your recommendations, I actually moved it all together into prepared query using `command.Parameters.Add` ; but while I am looking at your example (thanks for your help here), I am wondering if this is the best way of doing the insert?

Comment: @Andrew that depends on you and your needs. You can just as easily turn the insert into a stored procedure that you call, then you are only calling a sproc with parameters, thereby simplifying your C#. Another option is to use an ORM like nHibernate or Entity Framework, but that adds other levels of complexity that might not be needed. So, the answer as always is that it depends on your requirements. However, if you keep it at a query in the C#, then, yes that is the best way.

Answer (score 3):

I built this answer using your code as the example.  Take note of the following line:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@queryParam", Query);
```

It is always a best-practice to code for potential SQL Injection attacks *even if they are unlikely to happen*.

```
static String Server = "";
static String Username = "";
static String Name = "";
static String password = "";

static String conString = "SERVER=" + Server + ";DATABASE=" + Name + ";UID=" + Username  + ";PASSWORD=" + password + ";connect timeout=500000;Compress=true;";

public bool InsertSQL(String Query)
{
   int tmp = 0;
   try
   {
      using (MySqlConnection mycon = new MySqlConnection(conString))
      {
         using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(Query, mycon))
         {
            mycon.Open();
            try
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@queryParam", Query);
                tmp = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            catch
            {
                if (mycon.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    mycon.Close();
                }
            }
            mycon.Close();
         }
     }
 }
 catch { return tmp > 0 == true ? true : false; }
 return tmp > 0 == true ? true : false;
}
```